# Autopost with facebook graph api

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an iOS game that has some social features. I'm confused as to how to make an "autopost" functionality without prompting the user with a dialog box.

I'm kinda overwhelmed by the Facebook Graph API as I've been reading through it for about a day now.

From what I understood, I can make events such as User (performed action) on (an object). But what about "User has leveled up on (APPNAME)!"

How can I enable autopost? And how about 'event' type posts like the one mentioned above?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done. Here is a [link](http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-through.html) for it. Although, I should suggest that you should abstain from it as it would be considered spamming if you post a lot on the user's feed.